# Removing the casing from a mixer tap

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I'm trying to replace the cartridge in this mixer tap:

[image: Mixer tap]

I've watched a few videos online, and they all seem to indicate that the tap will have a screw holding it in place - the only one I can find is the one shown in the picture behind the cap.  The problem I have is that, when I take this off, the tap (cover?) just won't budge.  Is there something else I'm likely to need to do?  I thought it was maybe just stuck, but I've tried everything (wd40, pulling it, using a screwdriver to pry it, and lightly hammering to knock it loose).

Comment: Try describing the "everything" you've tried. Otherwise, people will waste a lot of time suggesting things you've already done.

Comment: That’s a fair point.  Obviously, ‘everything’ isn’t really everything.  I’ve basically tried pulling it, using a screwdriver to prise it, and lightly hammering to knock it loose.

Comment: That info should be in the question itself. I've put it there, but you're always free to [edit] it in yourself. That helps ensure others see it. Did any of those activities seem like they may have worked but it was stuck? I'd suggest possibly soaking it in some CLR™ (or similar), or maybe using a penetrating fluid like PB Blaster™ may help loosen it. Generally, if the screw in the end is loose, it should come straight off. Do you know the brand of faucet? That could help someone help you, too.

Comment: I did try WD40 (question updated), would the others not cause issues with the drinking water (given it's a tap)?  Unfortunately there's nothing on the tap itself to indicate a make.